# Maximum number of concurrent http connections in Google Cloudfunction

Tags: http, concurrency, google-cloud-functions

I must call an external API a certain amount of time from a Google Cloud Function. I must wait for all results before responding to the client. As I want to respond as quickly as I can, I want to make these calls async. But as I can get many calls (lets say, 250 or 1000+ calls), I'm wondering if there is a limit (there is certainly one..). I looked for the answer online, but all the things I found is about calling a CloudFunction concurrently which is not my problem here. I found some information about NodeJs, but nothing related to the CloudFunctions.

I'm using firebase.

I would also like to know if there is an easy way in in CloudFunction to use the maximum number of concurrent connections and queue the rest of the calls?

Comment: That limit is going to be based on the underlying operating system, not the product itself.  Each function runs in total isolation on different machines from other function invocations, so you will only be limited by the OS's ability to make outgoing sockets.  I strongly suspect you will not exceed that even with 1000 connections.  Honestly, you should just try it see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Cloud Functions each request is processed by 1 instance of the function and the instance can process only one request in the same time (no concurrent request processing -> 2 concurrents request create 2 Cloud Functions instances).

*Alternatively, with Cloud Run, you can process up to 80 request in the same time on the same instance. And so, for the same number of concurrent request, you have less instances (up to 80 time less) and because you pay the CPU and the memory, you will pay less with Cloud Run. I [wrote an (old) article on this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-vs-cloud-functions-whats-the-lowest-cost-728d59345a2e)*

The number of instance of a same Cloud Functions has been removed (previously, it was 1000). So, you don't have limit in the scalability (even if there is a physical limit when the region don't have enough resources to create a new instance of your function).

About the queue... There is not really a queue. the request is kept few seconds (about 10) and wait a new instance creation or a free instance (which just finish to process another request). After 10s, a 429 HTTP error code is returned.

---

About concurrent request on Cloud Functions I tested to call up to 25000 request in the same time and it works without issue.

However, you are limited by the function capacity (only 1 CPU, concurrency is limited) and the memory (boost the memory, boost the CPU speed and allows to handle more concurrent request -> I got a out of memory with 256Mb and 2500 concurrent requests test)

*I performed the test in Go*

Comment: My problem is not about running Cloud Functions concurrently. It's about running concurrent http calls from within a Cloud Function.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the misunderstood. AFAIK, there isn't limit on this, at least not documented limit. But a test is easy to do. Let me check if I have time for this.

Comment: I guess there is no documentation on this specific subject. I wonder if it could break in the future if I build a feature based on that.